# Synchronizing SQLite and MySql together

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sqlite, synchronization

I am trying to synchronize 2 different type of database together. Here is a better explanation of what I am trying to do:

I have the MySQL database on a server with the main database. I have an application installed on multiple computers.

I need the main database to be updated with the modification inside the computers and I need the computer version to get the updates from the main database.

I have seen the replication option in MySQL but it's not exactly what I want to do. I have seen other stuff like REPLACE INTO but I still don't see a clear solution.

I'm not asking for a full solution but maybe a good pseudocode or some cool functionality so I can try to implement it. This will be used on my end of school project.

I obviously have a timestamps on each row so I can detect changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this if I had an app that will run in different SQL environments.

It will be cleaner if you do the communication between yourApp & DB through some `php` class. This class instance will be created based on user's SQL version. Then, it is for your code in the class to decide how to connect to your DB.